# Where should an ember add-on place built assets

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember-addon, [ember-cli-grunticon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-grunticon), that turns svg’s into data uri classes, fallback pngs, etc. using [grunticon-lib](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon-lib).  The problem I’m finding is that doing this in a `preBuild` hook triggers another build if I push the results to `public/grunticon` (infinite builds - yeah!).  What’s the “right” way to serve these assets?